# Get wrapped component class from connected HOC in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, higher-order-components

When using the `connect` function in `react-redux`, a Higher Order Component is created.  From an instance of that HOC, one can access the wrapped *instance* of the extended component.  Is it possible, however, to retrieve the wrapped *class* from the HOC class?

E.g.:

```
class A extends React.Component {}

ConnectedA = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatch)(A);

ConnectedA.some_static_method_to_get_the_wrapped_class(); // === A
```

EDIT: For the sake of clarity, I do not have an instance of `ConnectedA` available.  I need a static method or property.  Does that exist?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to get from the `A` instance?

Comment: you should [read this](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/914)

Comment: @Sagivb.g  Thanks for the link!  It's however not what I need.  I need something that can retrieve the wrapped class from the connected class, without an instance ever existing.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use connected component [`getWrappedInstance` method](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#getwrappedinstance-reactcomponent) in conjunction with `withRef` option to get a ref of wrapped component:

```
this.aConnectedRef = React.createRef();

...

<ConnectedA ref={this.aConnectedRef} />

...

// after render
// this.aConnectedRef.current.getWrappedInstance() instanceof A === true
```

Wrapped class itself is available as `WrappedComponent` property:

```
ConnectedA.WrappedComponent === A
```

If `A` static method is needed then a reference to `A` class should be likely used directly, or it could be refactored to not require static method.

Comment: As a general FYI, note that this option will probably be removed in React-Redux v6, and replaced with a `forwardRef` option that will allow you to more directly get a ref to the wrapped component instance.