# Unable to find functions or node when testing a nested component in Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a specific component that is nested within two other components:

```
<Router>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Howitworks />
  </Provider>
</Router>
```

However when I try to run my test:

```
 test("should call onTaskerClick", () => {

   const spy = jest.spyOn(Howitworks.prototype, "onTaskerClick");
   const wrapper = mount(
     <Router>
       <Provider store={store}>
         <Howitworks />
       </Provider>
     </Router>
   );
   wrapper.find("#pills-tasker-tab.nav-link.tasklink").at(0).simulate("click");

   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

 });
```

I get a "spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given" error. I have tried different variations of mocking this "onTaskerClick" function when simulating a click on the link that invokes it but always get a variation of the error that the function is undefined or function was not called.

The link that invokes onTaskerClick:

```
 <a className='nav-link tasklink' id='pills-tasker-tab' data-toggle='pill' onClick={this.onTaskerClick} role='tab' aria-controls='pills-tasker' aria-selected='false'>LINK<span></span></a>
```

Here is how the Howitworks component is currently being exported:

```
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { onNotifyClick })(Howitworks);
```

Unfortunately there's very limited documentation on accessing functions within a nested component in a test environment so any help would be great.

EDIT:

Updated test suite:

```
 test("should call onTaskerClick", () => {

   const wrapper = mount(
     <Router>
       <Provider store={store}>
         <Howitworks />
       </Provider>
     </Router>
   );
   const spy = 
 jest.spyOn(wrapper.find(Howitworks.WrappedComponent).instance(), "onTaskerClick");
   wrapper.find("#pills-tasker-tab.nav-link.tasklink").at(0).simulate("click");

   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

mapStateToProps function and export:

```
 let mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { onNotifyClick })(Howitworks);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect` returns a higher-order component that doesn't inherit from original component, which is common in React.

In order for `onTaskerClick` to be spyable on a prototype, it should be prototype and not instance (arrow) method. Original component class can be either separate named export:

```
export class Howitworks {
  onTaskerClick() {...}
  ...
}

export default connect(...)(Howitworks);
```

Or it can be accessed on connected component as [`WrappedComponent` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316145/3731501).

Since `onTaskerClick` isn't called on component instantiation, there's no need to spy on a prototype, it's easier to do this on an instance, this doesn't limit a spy to prototype methods:

```
   const wrapper = mount(...);
   const origComp = wrapper.find(Howitworks.WrappedComponent).instance();
   const spy = jest.spyOn(origComp, "onTaskerClick");
   origComp.forceUpdate();
   // trigger click
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I still get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'onTaskerClick' of null

Comment: Yea I used last one. What solution should I use because the onTaskerClick is an arrow function in Howitworks.

Comment: I tried using WrapperComponent but still getting Received number of calls: 0

Comment: Then that you tried to spy on an arrow with Howitworks.prototype is wrong, only the last has a chance to work. Since it doesn't cause errors that could indicate problems with a spy, I'd expect it to work. Please, update the question with full component and your current test attempt. It's unclear what's wrong on your side.

Comment: I didn't use prototype. Please see my updated test suite. I'm also unable to post the full component but it is a class component where the arrow function onTaskerClick changes a 'step' value in the state to 'tasker'. I also added the mapStateToProps function in the op maybe that will give additional information.

Comment: I see. The problem is that original onTaskerClick has already been registered at the time of click. The component needs to be re-rendered in order to register a spy as click handler. See the update. Proto methods with `bind` are more preferable as callbacks than arrows because they are more testable and allow to additionally use option 1, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882417/3731501 , this is useful because option 2 is not always available.

Comment: If none of these options were available (this would happen for functional comp), you'd need to spy on effects that onTaskerClick causes rather than itself.

Comment: Thanks for all the info I learned a lot lol. Also the updated works and the test passes now